# Is there any way to get limited access to user data (specific to an organisation) using any of the auth flows?

Tags: docusignapi

Use case: I have an organisation set up in DocuSign admin. I also have an internal application. I use auth code grant to get individual consent for user data. I don't want to get an access token that can be used to fetch data from the user's personal account, just the account associated with the organisation.

**userinfo** api let's me choose which **account_id** to fetch data for. But I want to limit access at individual consent phase only. Is it possible to do so?

Answer (score 0):

You can define [the authentication scope](https://developers.docusign.com/platform/auth/reference/scopes/) when granting consent to your application. If you don't request for any user scopes (user_read,user_write) then any requests with the associated auth token won't be able to access user data

Comment: I believe user_read, user_write are Docusign Admin scopes. My use case here is different. The access token that is generated for an individual user is tied to their user id. His user id might be tied to [personal profile, org 1, org 2] accounts. What I want the user's access token to access is just data for org 1, because that's the org I added the user to from DS Admin.

Answer (score 0):

Re:

> I don't want to get an access token that can be used to fetch data from the user's personal account, just the account associated with the organisation.

All eSign data access requires an access token that is associated with a user that has access to the data.

If you want programmatic access to any data in an account then you need an access token associated with a system administrator for that account. (There may be data that is not accessible to an account system admin, I'm not expert on that issue.)